# Want 3 rows in my input text area comments instead of one

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, bootstrap-4

Using Bootstrap 4.3.1 with react
Currently, I have this [image]

And I want to achieve this 
[image]

```
comments: {
        elementLabel: "Comments",
        elementType: 'textarea',
        elementConfig: {
            placeholder: '',
            name: "comments",
            id: "comments",
            rows: 4
        },
        value: '',
        form_value: "",
        validation: {
        },
        valid: false,
        touched: false,
        isChanged: false,
        errorMessage: "",
        className: "form-control",
        changed: (event) => this.inputChangedHandler(event, "comments"),
        blured: (event) => this.inputBlurHandler(event, "comments")
    },
```

Tried using above change in commnets but doesnot helps

```
<div className="form-row mb-3">
                                    <div className="col-md-12">
                                            <Input
                                                {...this.state.comments}
                                            />  </div>
                                </div>
```

Also this is the case of My `input` component where `textarea` is getting render.

```
 case ('textarea'):
        inputElement = (
            <React.Fragment>
                <label>{ReactHtmlParser(props.elementLabel)}</label>
                <textarea
                    {...props.elementConfig}
                    className={inputClass}
                    value={props.value}
                    onChange={props.changed}
                    onBlur={props.blured}
                />
                {
                    invalidClass || props.allowed_characters
                        ?
                        <div className="form-row">
                            <div className={`col-md-10  text-left`}>
                                {invalidClass ? <span className="invalid-feedback">{props.errorMessage}</span> : null}
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-2 text-right">
                                {
                                    props.allowed_characters ?
                                        <span className="allowed_characters">{props.current_character_count} / {props.allowed_characters}</span>
                                        : null
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        :
                        null
                }

            </React.Fragment>
        )
```

Tried passing external scss but that does not help, what to do now?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not willing to use the textarea you can use the CSS to make the input element width and height like text area.

A good practice is to use textarea only for such cases. In React try to pass rows and cols like this:

```
<textarea rows={4} cols={8} />
```

PS: but that will not give the feature of wrapping the text to the new line.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I want to know if there is any reason you are not using textarea, because I see that you are using input element.

Comment: because of the reason that we are using input only for that

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot do it with input element, as suggested by @Michael, you will have to use <textarea /> can you create codesandbox or codepen so we can help you with it.

Comment: updated the question, Added Input component `case` where this getting render

Comment: Which framework are you using for react for Bootstrap?

Comment: @Farhan Not quite getting the question, perhaps a sandbox will help alot

Comment: react bootstrap

Comment: There are lot of errors on codesandbox, I have rectified it but now I am getting error as list is empty in state. Would it be possible for you create dummy data or something that we can debug without it.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple line input I think you should just use

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="3">Somethine like this &#13;&#10;for&#13;&#10;different lines</textarea>
```

Comment: I tried but didn't work on my solution, passes `rows: 4 ` did not work

Comment: @Farhan Your title says you want 3 rows, but even if you want 4 rows it stills works `<textarea cols="50" rows="4">Somethine like this &#13;&#10;for&#13;&#10;different lines&#13;&#10;and another one</textarea>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve desired functionality by using textarea in the following way :

[image]

Comment: He is trying to achieve it in react with some framework, I think

Comment: @Farhan send 4 as string like this "4"

Comment: Please check what @Mohit suggested may be that could help!

Comment: Hi @Farhan, here is the working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wind-winy5, I have created a textarea with 3 rows with minimum functionality from your sandbox.